# Recognize numbers using gestures

Tags: android, gesture-recognition

I want to recognize numbers using gestures through coding. I've recognized using gesture library. Is there any possibility to recognize numbers perfectly?

Please suggest any sample code.

Comment: It all depends on the database

Comment: If user writes some digit 0-9 i've to recognize it. Though i used gesture library it is not recognizing perfectly...so wanna go with program...

Comment: wat is database here in this context?

Comment: I have to programs that recognize simbols (Gesture Call is one of them, u can find it in the market) and allways the problem to recognize a symbol-number-letter are the database.

You can create a database symbols with the app in the android sdk "Gesture Builder" and try to create a good database. Yoy can create a few gestures for each number. But the problem is that the user probably will not have your calligraphy and a database with a lot of gestures for each number probably be diverted to some symbols.


*Database is the Store item you in the gesture library

Comment: i've already done it...but it was not perfectly recognizing the numbers.

Comment: @Aracem let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2727/discussion-between-ammu-and-aracem)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you mean by perfectly?  As in successfully detect the number the user intended to gesture  100% of the time?  As long as your users are human, this isn't possible.  4 can look like 9, 1 can look like 7, and depending on how quickly they swipe, what started out as a 0 can end up looking like a 6 (or vice versa).  Every individual gestures differently than everyone else, and every time you gesture a 4, it's going to look just a little more or less different from your 9, as well as all your other 4's.

One possible solution is to have your app contain a "learning mode" which asks the user to gesture out a specific digits several times, so that you can pick up on patterns (where they start, where they stop, how many swipes are included, how big it is), and use those to narrow things down when the app is actually used.  Sort of like a good spam filter-  It won't get you 100% detection rate, but it'll definitely get you a lot closer than not having a data set to work off of.